# Counting ipywidgets Intslider steps in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

I am using the `IntSlider()` method from the `ipywidgets()` class to visualize and record the count for each step of a parameter in a seaborn `Kdeplot()`. Any quick fix is deeply appreciated. Thanks

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Play
from IPython.display import display
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

```
cars = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
```

```
@widgets.interact(bw=(.1,5,.1))
def bandwidth(bw=0):
    sns.kdeplot(cars.horsepower,lw=3,fill=True,bw_adjust=bw)
    plt.xlim(-20,200)
    plt.ylim(0, 0.04);
```

The widgets work well, but I need a way to record/capture the count (Good and Bad) of each step move in the slider; hopefully get the data in a list or table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly what you are trying to describe? And your title seems generally vague? Your title "Counting ipywidgets Intslider steps in Jupyter notebook" suggests you want to count the number steps? Isn't the number of steps derivable from `bw=(.1,5,.1)` which describes the range and the step size? Or do you mean the number of steps you like in some way?  Or maybe the number of actual points below or above the continuous probability density curve for each step? ...

Comment: You say, "I am using the IntSlider() method from the ipywidgets() class to visualize and record the count for each step of a parameter". I'm missing how you are doing that 'record the count' part? Unless you are meaning you want to do that? Incidentally while the slider use may be a nice way to dial in to visualize various settings, it doesn't seem like the systematic way to go about actually counting and recording at each step if that is the actual intent? I don't see why the sliders really help get you to where you need to get? But like I prefaced, maybe I'm not understanding what you want.

Comment: @Wayne, thanks, at least, for your comments. The problem I'm trying to solve (maybe I didn't describe it well!) is to find a way to generate some data (into a list or table) for each time I move the slider. In essence, I don't need the values of `bw`, instead I need to move the slider, look at the `kdeplot`, make a decision, and record that move as either a good plot or not (1 or 0) in a list or a table. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: The issue is how systematic and how is the 'decision' made? If you are going to simply do this for each step and the basis of the decision can be described in code, it would seem much more fruitful to automate all that in a separate Python script or Python-based Jupyter notebook and then use the Jupyter notebook with the slider to just get back to the settings you like out of what the quantified data says. On the other hand, if you are only checking a few steps, you just open a spreadsheet in another window and record the information. You could of course code a separate notebook that has ...

Comment: <continued>  ipywidgets that allow you to record the settings you need as you go along and have that open as you analyze your slider view notebook in another pane in JupyterLab. You could make the GUI as ornate or as simple as you need. And then have a cell at the end that outputs that data to a TSV/CSV file.  JupyterLab let's you arrange two notebooks side-by-side in your window and so it would be best. If you absolutely wanted to make more effort, you could build in to the same notebook the widgets for recording as you went along, but that seems like you'd be going out of your way to ...

Comment: <continued> to make a GUI of something that could just be written down in another screen or on paper.

Comment: In case, I wasn't clear... the automation approach wouldn't really involve a slider. You'd just do all the calculations and 'decisions' separate and ahead of time. (You could even make all the plots, too. Or thumbnails of them.) The slider would just be for viewing yourself later, after-the-fact. (Of courrse, if you made the images as you went through the steps, you wouldn't really need the slider. And that is why I'm not understanding your need for a slider really.)

Comment: But maybe it is all too subjective of a 'decision' to make the calls automated. Which is a question I also wasn't gathering in your post.

Comment: Wow, thanks once again for the insights. May slider may be off it, but I'd try making a GUI perhaps from `tkinter` library or try a combination of python `input()` and `ipywidget` checkbox.

Comment: No need to use tkinter. You can make the GUI with ipywidgets right in the Jupyter notebook and then run the same notebook as an app using [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila#). (`input()` isn't a ipwidget though so it won't work in Voila.) Lots of Voila examples at [the Voila Gallery](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila#the-voil%C3%A0-gallery). All of the examples are just notebooks rendered with Voila.

Comment: Thanks, @Wayne. I really appreciate your painstaking insights. I'll sure take a look at Voilà.